# Stack sparse matricies with different arrays in Python

Tags: python, bigdata, sparse-matrix

I have some nlp data in sparseDataFrame variables with N columns each. I need to stack these variables to create an MxN csv sparse file.
I tried to convert the sparseDataFrame variables with sparse.csr_matrix, and then use vstack to stack the resulting vector rows. However, the shape of the matrices created by sparse.csr_matrix was (1,K) with K being different for each matrix (simply, its the highest column index with a non-zero argument), this causes vstack to fail.

For example after converting two sparseDataFrame variables with 10 columns I get:

```
  IN[]    print(A)
 OUT[]    (0, 0)    1
          (0, 3)    4

  IN[]    print(B)
 OUT[]    (0, 1)    1

  IN[]    C = vstack((A,B),format='csr')
```

I get `ValueError: incompatible dimensions for axis 1`.

Anyway to simply append my M 1 dimensional sparseDataFrames / sparseMatricies to MxN sparse mtx / sparse csv file?

Thanks

Comment: Please include a specific example we can use to reproduce the problem.  You've described the problem well, but a concrete example would nail this down for many more people.  Also, what is the source of sparseDataFrame?  R has such a type, but it's not native to Python.  Clarify, please?